# Attempt to update users table generates MethodNotAllowedHttpException, Laravel-4

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

UsersController:

```
public function update($id)
    {
        if( ! $this->user->isValid(Input::all()))
             {
                 return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->user->errors);
             }

        $user = $this->user->find($id);

        $user->save();

        return Redirect::route('users.index');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

Model:

```
protected $table = 'users'
```

edit.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route'=>array('users.update','$user'=>'id'))) }}
```

I notice that this does NOT generate a "PUT" action. The page source:

```
    <form method="POST" action="https://zocios.com/users/id" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="...">
```

Hitting the Update User button gets me:

```
Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Is the problem "$user->save();"? Something else I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the method:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('method' => 'put', 'route'=>array('users.update','$user'=>'id'))) }}
```

There is no other method than `GET` and `POST` that is accepted (despite the specs), so the framework does the job of identyfying hidden input in your form `_method` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! That works. But then a new error pops up that I hadn't seen before: "Creating default object from empty value". It seems to be referring to the password field, but of course I'm entering the password. If I leave it blank, it simply reloads the form, but when I include it I get the error. It works fine when used for initial entry, but fails with the update. (Sorry for my delayed reply; I had to be offline for a couple of days.)

Comment: I doubt it comes from the password. Try here `$this->user->find()` - are you sure you have `$this->user` injected?